# How to add new worksheets in a excel workbook in a particular position using the Sheets.Add method

Tags: excel, vb.net, com

I am creating a workbook which by default comes with one sheet. I want to add 5 more sheets which I am able to do. But when no position of insertion is specified the sheets are added before the active sheet, in this case `Sheet1`. But I want to insert these pages after `Sheet1` and hence tried using the 'After' parameter of the ADD method (see code below). But got the following error: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '0x800A03EC'`. How to correct this?

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module Program
    Dim oxl As Excel.Application
    Dim owbs As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim owb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim osheets As Object

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim pos As Object = "Sheet1"
        oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oxl.DisplayAlerts = True
        oxl.Visible = True
        owb = oxl.Workbooks.Add
        Console.WriteLine("Enter key to add 5 worksheets")
        Console.ReadLine()
        'Adds 5 sheets before 'Sheet1' - default active sheet
        osheets = owb.Worksheets.Add(, pos, 5,) 'Getting Error
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: `pos` has to be a worksheet-object - not the name itself, like `set pos = owb.worksheets("sheet1")` - but you have to put this line of code after the creation of owb!!